# How to recover files after encrypting whole disk with LUKS?

Tags: data-recovery, luks

During Debian 11 installation by error I encrypted (LUKS) the whole HDD with personal data.

During the process it said "data will be erased, irreversible, are you sure?" etc.

Now, after unlocking it doesn't show up in the file manager.

Executed the `DISKS` utility, and it shows an encrypted whole disk without any kind of file system (`ext4`, `ntfs`, `fat32`, etc).
So basically it didn't add partitions.

Did nothing to it yet, not to damage sectors/overwrite possible data.

Its possible to recover files in such a situation?

Comment: Did the installer run to completion, or did you interrupt it? The installer might pre-fill the encrypted volume with random data to make it harder for an attacker to analyze which parts of the encrypted disk might be actual data and which parts are unused. If that process ran to completion, then everything that was under the LUKS container is now overwritten and very effectively lost forever.

Comment: If it began to create a LUKS encrypted partition it will have most likely have written the LUKS header to the start of the partition which is usually 16 MB. That can do a lot of damage to your filesystem.  Depending on what else it did, there may be recovery tools that can scan the rest of the space for files.  Obviously the more it wrote, the less you might have left.

Comment: LUKS finished the whole process, not added partitions though

Comment: It is possible if LUKS only added a header, try this: https://www.r-studio.com/?GIMCX000 If LUKS overwrote the entire disk, the data is gone forever.

Comment: "The whole process" is usually just writing the header. AFAIK LUKS doesn't spontaneously write anything to the rest of the disk. The rest of the disk remains uninitialised and untouched until you write something to the "unlocked device" like formatting it with a filesystem.